# Grep links to Twitter from a web page

Tags: google-sheets

I am using this formula to get all link URLs from a website:

`=importxml("http://centegix.com", "//@href")`

How can I get only the URLs that point to Twitter?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider showing your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()`, like this:

`=query( importxml("http://centegix.com", "//@href"), "where Col1 contains 'twitter' ", 0 )`